# Choleski decomposition of a positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let us consider a matrix $\boldsymbol{F}$. We consider its Choleski decomposition,

$ \boldsymbol{F} = \boldsymbol{M} \boldsymbol{M}^T $.

We know that $\boldsymbol{F}$ needs to be positive definite.
Let us make a further assumption: $\boldsymbol{F}$ is positive, in the sense that none of its entries is negative.

My question is: given this further hypothesis, is $\boldsymbol{M}$ positive too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.  In particular, if we take
$$
F = 
\pmatrix{
1&1&1\\
1&2&1/2\\
1&1/2&9/4
}
$$
Then we find
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&-1/2&1}
$$
It is true, however, for all $2 \times 2$ matrices.